# избавиться от INTERSECT

Tags: sql

**Найти все платежи, где счет плательщика и получателя имеет тип "Расчетный счет"**

не могу избаиться от INTERSECT,
двух JOINов сделать не получается из-за обращения к одной таблице

```
select payment.* from payment
join account on payment.payer_account_id = account.id
where account.account_name = 'расчетный счет'
intersect
select payment.* from payment
join account on payment.receiver_account_id = account.id
where account.account_name = 'расчетный счет';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select payment.* 
from payment
join account a1 on payment.payer_account_id = a1.id
join account a2 on payment.receiver_account_id = a2.id
where a1.account_name = 'расчетный счет'
  and a2.account_name = 'расчетный счет';
```